# Why energy calculation can sum different runtime?

Tags: power

page.3,  equation (1)
http://webee.technion.ac.il/~ran/papers/ERotemHeteroEARtH.pdf

Ef = ( tc + tm ) x ( Pc + Pl )

what if tc and tm are overlapped?

I mean if run time only happens 1 second, tc and tm happened in the same 1 second.

can we still calculate the energy in this way?

**Edit update:**

My understanding about energy calculation should be:

Energy_Total = Power_of_memory x Memory_Runtime + Power_of_CPU x CPU_Runtime

I think the result will be different if we sum them up (I think this is wrong), ex:

Energy_Total = ( Power_of_memory + Power_of_CPU ) x ( CPU_Runtime + Memory_Runtime )

**Update:**

In this paper, it identifies at run time which core to use and at what frequency, in order to achieve the global minimum platform energy.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Mark. Can you edit your question to include enough information that we don't need to follow the link to understand what is being asked? Also, you are missing some capitalisation in the title and question which should be tidied up. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the site guidelines.

Comment: Yes, please edit the question to provide the context! And I don't see power and time being added together as the title suggests.

Comment: Also note that the question is not about a general EE formula but about some specific *model* for computer power estimation described in the paper. So don't expect people to immediately know what you mean.

Comment: "what if tc and tm are overlapped?" - From a quick glance at the diagram on page 2, t[c] and t[m] don't overlap *by definition*. The CPU is either *active* busy (t[c]) *or* *active* waiting for memory (t[m]), it can't be both busy and waiting for memory at the same time.

Comment: I think the equation Ef = (tc + tm) x ( Pc + Pl) is simply an energy and power equation, ex: Energy = Power x Time, but I don't know why they can sum up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why power is lower if memory accesses are spread over a longer time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433977/why-power-is-lower-if-memory-accesses-are-spread-over-a-longer-time)

Comment: no, my question is different, you can find the part of Edit update.

Comment: No, it is the same question.  You just have not taken time to understand it.  Further, your very statement of the question is mistaken - power and time are *multiplied*, not *summed*.  Finally, questions which cannot be made sense of without following external links are prohibited; questions are required to stand on their own.

Comment: suggest to point out why they are the same question.

Comment: I modified the title, but I think the problem is still as the part of 'Edit update'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From figure 2 in that link.

Tc (Tcpu) and Tm (Tmem) are not overlapped.

When CPU job is done, the data transfer to off-chip memory.

These two run time are not overlapped.

Comment: In Equation (1),  Ef=(tc + tm) x (Pc + Pl), this is reasonable, but why tc=tc0/fc ?

Comment: fc = factual / f0; tc = tc0 x f0 / factual ; tc = constant_hit / factual ; tc = tc